# Convert mpf of mpmath to python float to support cvxopt

Tags: python-2.7, cvxopt

I am working on CVXOPT using qudratic programing problem.To create a G matrix, i need to differentiate the equation and compute the values.For differentiation i used Sympy.mpmath and lambda function as given below.I am getting the output in mpf format.Please suggest me a way to convert mpf to python float format that supports CVXOPT. 
Thankyou

```
dg1 = np.array([sp.mpmath.diff(lambda x1,x2,x3,x4,x5:0.75*x2/x4,(0.3,1.45,5,1.1,0.25),ft[i]) for i in range(n)])                 
>>>array([mpf('0.0'), mpf('0.68181818181818177'), mpf('0.0'),
   mpf('-0.89876033057851223'), mpf('0.0')], dtype=object)
```

Comment: if we use sympy.mpmath.nstr(), I am getting the output in the form of string as given below:'[0.0, 0.681818, 0.0, -0.89876, 0.0]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your `sp.mpmath.diff` call with `float(...)`:

```
dg1 = np.array([float(sp.mpmath.diff(lambda x1,x2,x3,x4,x5:0.75*x2/x4,
                                     (0.3,1.45,5,1.1,0.25),ft[i])) for i in range(n)])

>>>array([0.        , 0.68181818, 0.        , -0.89876033, 0.        ])
```

Comment: Great! I'm really happy I helped you, and I would appreciate if you mark my answer as an accepted one.